# Getting the optical power of a UV-LED using a spectrometer data

Tags: led, optoelectronics, uv

if it is possible can you let me know the way to get the radiated power of a UV-LED using the output data from the "Ocean optics- Maya pro 2000" spectrometer, or the calculations needed to calculate it from that data.

in the data sheet of the UV-LED the radiated power is from 2mW(min) to 6mW(max) at 40mA current, i uploaded a screenshot for the spectrometer data.

thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: well, what is the unit of "power"? What do you get in data? What is missing to convert one to the other? This is pure logical thinking!

Comment: @MarcusMüller hello sir, i take the second last unit from the the table "uWatt/cm2" and i convert it to mWatt/cm2, in this case 1.36E4 X E-6 to get 13.6mWatt, but i am not sure if i am correct or not.

Comment: ... how do you do that conversion? (also, you haven't answered "what is missing to convert one to the other", and that's where the trick lies!)

Comment: @MarcusMüller i was trying to convert the micro watt/cm2 to milli watt/cm2, i don't know if i am right and what is missing to convert, if you can explain it to me i would be grateful sir

Comment: but that's not the unit of *power*, that's the unit of *area power density*. You need to be 100% clear what you need, and the math will come to you.

Comment: @MarcusMüller the radiated power unit should be only in "watt"

Comment: Exactly! So, what's missing?

Comment: @MarcusMüller i should use the last unit in the table "uWatt"?

Comment: no. What is missing that you can convert *area power density* to *power*?

Comment: @MarcusMüller by taking the "uWatt/cm2" and multiply it to the area of the cross section area?

Answer (score 0):

You might need an [integrating sphere](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_sphere) accessory. It's a reflecting hollow sphere, used to get most photons into the spectrometer. Hopefully the sphere is pre-calibrated. Then you take a reading and an integration over the wavelentghs is required.

Frankly speaking [radiant flux measurement](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiometry) is one of the more complicated measurements to do.

Either invest 1000+ bucks into equipment or into a service doing it for you.

Maybe think twice if you really need to check this parameter.

LEDs from trustworthy manufacturers mostly (nearly) meet the proposed values when: new and cold.